# Grails Dojo ItemFileReadStore

Tags: grails, dojo

Setting up a simple grails app with Dojo, i used the

```
grails install-plugin dojo
```

to setup the dojo js files. In my main.gsp i have this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails" /></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'css',file:'main.css')}" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${resource(dir:'images',file:'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon" />
    <g:layoutHead />
    <g:javascript library="application"/>
    <g:javascript library="dojo"/>
    <dojo:header modules="['dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore','dijit.form.ComboBox']"/>
    <g:javascript>
        //dojo.addOnLoad(function(){alert("dojo loaded.");});
    </g:javascript>
</head>
```

On my index.gsp page, i setup the following elements

```
        <div>
        <div jsId="search" dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore"
            url="<g:createLink controller="runner" action="findrunner"/>"></div>

            <input dojoType="dojo.data.FilteringSelect"
                id="chooser"
                name="feed"
                store="search"
                searchAttr="url"
                autocomplete="true"
                pageSize="5"/>

        </div>
```

Start the app but keep getting this error from firebug

```
GET http://localhost:8080/xxx/js/dojo/1.4.3/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.js

404 Not Found
        5ms 
dojo.js (line 16)
ParamsHeadersPostPutResponseCacheHTML

..</head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - /xxx/js/dojo/1.4.3/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.js</h1>
<HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> 
<u>/xxx/js/dojo/1.4.3/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.js</u></p><p><b>description</b> 
<u>The requested resource (/xxx/js/dojo/1.4.3/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.js) is not available.</u>
</p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0-snapshot</h3></body></html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the 'dojo plugin' didn't seems to install all the required dojo files. I manually installed [dojo 1.5](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.5.0/dojo-release-1.5.0.zip) and extract the zip to /webapps/js/dojo/1.5.0 and enabled the version in my main.gsp like this

```
<script src="js/dojo/1.5.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The new plugin version makes things a lot easier now. There is even a script to launch your custom builds in a breeze... and it's updated to dojo 1.6. Give it a try ;-)